# Dynamically center and adjust UILabel width programmatically

Tags: ios, uilabel

It seems like something simple but I can't get it work the way I want it,
there are many similar question here but non of them solved my problem.

i'm using the following code to set a view centered in its superview

with two UILabels as subviews, also the number of points changes.

```
NSString *myScoreText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score: "];
UIFont *myScoreFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myScoreFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
CGFloat myScoreWidth = [myScoreText sizeWithAttributes:attributes].width;

NSString *pointsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d points", currentScore];
UIFont *pointsFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pointsFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
CGFloat pointsWidth = [pointsText sizeWithAttributes:attributes].width;

CGFloat scoreViewWidth = myScoreWidth + pointsWidth;
UIView *scoreView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(FRAME_WIDTH/2 - scoreViewWidth/2, elementHeight, scoreViewWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT)];

UILabel *myScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myScoreWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT)];
myScoreLabel.font = myScoreFont;
myScoreLabel.text = myScoreText;
myScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

self.pointsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myScoreWidth, 0, pointsWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT)];
self.pointsLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.pointsLabel.font = pointsFont;
self.pointsLabel.text = pointsText;
self.pointsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

[scoreView addSubview:myScoreLabel];
[scoreView addSubview:self.pointsLabel];
```

after the view is displayed it works fine when points are between 10-99 but if the points increase to over 100 points the view displays the text like: `My Score: 100 po...` instead of `My Score: 100 points` and when score is over 1000 then the view displays `My Score: 1000 p...` and so on...

so how can i have all the text displayed correctly and still keep the view with its two UILabels subviews centered?

Thanks

Comment: You need the solution using autolayout??

Comment: I need a solution that can be achieved programmatically (no storyboard or xibs), if I can use autolayout that way then yes

Answer (score 0):

With Autolayout:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initForAutoLayout];

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= NO;


[self.view addSubview:label];

[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0f]];







 [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop   
     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual   
toItem:self.view
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    
   multiplier:1.0     
     constant:100.0]];

label.text = @"a";
```

With Purelayout:

Add the following PureLayout library

https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout

as it is relatively easy to handle autolayout using Purelayout.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initForAutoLayout];

[scoreView addSubview:label];

[label autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop withInset:0.0f];

[label autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisVertical];

[label setText:@"hello"];
```

text is centred by using ALAxisVertical, also you can centre it horizontally using ALAxisHorizontal.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but I was looking for a solution without outside libraries